# DISTINCT with LIMIT performance

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan

> It is important to note that combining DISTINCT with LIMIT can have a negative impact on performance. This is because the database engine must first find all of the non-duplicate rows in the result set before it can fetch the number of LIMIT rows.

> For example, consider the following SQL query:

> SELECT DISTINCT name FROM customers LIMIT 10;

> This query will return the names of the first 10 customers, without duplicates. To answer this query, the database engine must first find all of the unique customer names in the customers table. Once it has done that, it can then return the first 10 unique customer names.

I have read the above information on the internet.

My question: for the above query, why the sql execution need to find all of the non-duplicate rows in the result set **before** it can fetch the number of LIMIT rows?

Why not iterate from the first record to the end record of the customer table and collect non-duplicate results. If collect enough 10 non-duplicate results, break? So we don't need to find all non-duplicate rows in the customer table?

Comment: The DBMS cannot know what are all the distinct values until it examines each and every one of them.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server doesn't support that exact syntax but for the same basic query it could navigate an index ordered by `name` and feed that into a stream aggregate and stop requesting rows after the first 10 have been found. Or if no such index and an arbitrary `TOP 10` it could still use a hash match flow distinct that also stops after 10 unique values have been found

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Table DDL please?

Comment: If it stops at say row 100, how does it know that 101 is not a duplicate

Comment: @RohitGupta - once it has returned 10 distinct names it doesn't have to care about that

Answer (score 1):

"select distinct" is always a big Red Flag for me.

This, innocuous little statement ...

```
select distinct a, b, c, d ...
```

... usually performs on a par with this ...

```
select a, b, c, d 
group by a, b, c, d 
order by a, b, c, d
```

Working through the table, your DBMS has to find tuples it hasn't seen so far.
Either it has to "loop through" or somehow "hash" into its own, ongoing results or, more simply, get all the results and then sort them.  LIMIT always happens last so all that work gets done before LIMIT gets a look in.

In my experience, using distinct *almost always* indicates a different problem.
It might be with the joins used in a query ...

> I've got "duplicate" rows in my results, but 'distinct' makes them go away!

... or with the underlying data structures themselves.

Comment: FWIW, the reasons you conclude with for why `DISTINCT` is a red flag, is also just as true as someone using `GROUP BY` too (to workaround an unintended data duplication issue). I agree that a `DISTINCT` *can* be a red flag, but I still recommend using the right clauses for the situations they're meant for, to show better intent in the code, from a readability standpoint. I.e. `GROUP BY` shows intent of data aggregation. The exception I have to this though is if for the given situation, there is a measurable performance difference between query plans, making it worth using the other clause.

Comment: Absolutely agree.  DISTINCT /can/ be the Right Tool for the Right Job but it is also widely (and easily) abused.  All too often, I've seen [adjectives deleted] Developers when their queries start "misbehaving" and producing "duplicate" rows.  Rather than fix the /actual/ problem, they just slap a DISTINCT on the front and /their/ problem "goes away" ...   but the DBAs could be in for a rough ride when the database is hobbled by the overhead that query introduces.